# Selenium Webdriver: Restrict tests to specific platform in Grid

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a problem with the setup of my remote webdriver session that seemingly appeared overnight. My code used to work but now when I try to pass a value of platform as a capability I'm getting this error:

```
session not created: No matching capabilities found
```

My Java code to setup my Webdriver object looks like this:

```
private void setupRemoteDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
    // Set browser to Chrome
    ChromeOptions capability = new ChromeOptions();

    // Restrict to an OS platform if requested (ANY / VISTA / WIN10)
    capability.setCapability("platform", PLATFORM);

    // Create new remote webdriver session
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://" + SELENIUM_HOST + ":" + SELENIUM_PORT + "/wd/hub"),
            capability);
```

My Selenium Grid has the following nodes in it, you can see values for platform of VISTA and WIN10.

[image]

If I set PLATFORM='ANY', my tests run without issue.

However I need to run my full suite in both Windows 7 and Windows 10. When I pass a value of VISTA or WIN10 my tests fail to create a webdriver session. Here is the full output:

```
session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'VDCW764DED019', ip: '172.16.216.46', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
 Ordinal0 [0x0031A903+1550595]
 Ordinal0 [0x0029A701+1025793]
 Ordinal0 [0x0021C6E5+509669]
 Ordinal0 [0x001CA698+173720]
 Ordinal0 [0x001CA9CA+174538]
 Ordinal0 [0x001CA8ED+174317]
 Ordinal0 [0x001C8CDB+167131]
 Ordinal0 [0x001B144A+70730]
 Ordinal0 [0x001B24D0+74960]
 Ordinal0 [0x001B2469+74857]
 Ordinal0 [0x002B42C7+1131207]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x003B70FD+523789]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x003B6E90+523168]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x003BE1E7+552695]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x003B78FA+525834]
 Ordinal0 [0x002AB7FC+1095676]
 Ordinal0 [0x002B633B+1139515]
 Ordinal0 [0x002B64A3+1139875]
 Ordinal0 [0x002B5425+1135653]
 BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7561343D+18]
 RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77A99802+99]
 RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77A997D5+54]
```

I've tried using DesiredCapabilities instead of ChromeOptions but get the same result.

```
private void setupRemoteDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
    // Set browser to Chrome

    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

    // Restrict to an OS platform if requested (ANY / VISTA / WIN10)
    capability.setCapability("platform", PLATFORM);

    // Create new remote webdriver session
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://" + SELENIUM_HOST + ":" + SELENIUM_PORT + "/wd/hub"),
            capability);
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You probably need to update your browser's driver version

Comment: @KausUntwale, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that and still get the same result. My first thought was perhaps that Chrome had auto-updated.

Comment: One thing though your list of capabilities has all win10 which still makes me think that you dont have the correct driver when you use win7 as the parameter. Maybe you need a separate 32 bit driver for when you run on the 32 bit OS.